# get current page number with wp_link_pages()

Tags: plugins, posts, codex

I would like to get only the current page number (without HTML).

I'm using

```
wp_link_pages( array ( 'pagelink' => '%' ) );
```

How can I do that?

I'm also using this code in my theme:

```
function single_split_page($defaults) {
$args = array(
'before' => '<div class="single-split-page"><p>' . __('<strong>Pages</strong>','theasd'),
'after' => '</p></div>',
'pagelink' => '%',
);
$r = wp_parse_args($args, $defaults);
return $r;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wp_link_pages` [depends on four `global`s](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8/src/wp-includes/post-template.php#L656)-- `$page`, `$numpages`, `$multipage`, and `$more`.

I cannot test this right now, but if I remember correctly `$page` is the current page and `$numpages` is the total number of pages. All you should need is:

```
global $page;
echo $page;
```